# SPLanguageSettings.PreferredDisplayLanguages vs SPLanguageSettings.PreferredDisplayLanguagesNoClient?

Tags: localization

I tried to debug and found that the collection these both are identical:

- `SPLanguageSettings.PreferredDisplayLanguages`
- `SPLanguageSettings.PreferredDisplayLanguagesNoClient`

I then tried to add a new language e.g. `ja` (Japanese) in Internet Options > General > Languages such. That language appeared in **both** of the collections mentioned above.